# Building Linux Kernel without Repartitioning

Tags: linux-kernel

How should I go about building and testing the Linux kernel without repartitioning my system, or is that a requirement if I want to maintain my current setup?

Answer (score 1):

You can stuff several hundred kernels into your `/boot/` directory, assuming you created it large enough when you partitioned your drive. If `/boot` isn't its own filesystem, then it will share your root `/`, and that is typically 8-12 gigabytes in size, and frequently has four to six gigabytes free, which will hold a lot of kernels. :)

If the modifications to your kernel have the very real potential to corrupt data, you might wish to use [kvm+qemu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel-based_Virtual_Machine) for your testing kernels. Of course, it's quite hard to test hardware this way; there's nothing quite like having a 'crashbox' with *no* important data on it when you're performing hardware-driver testing.